# how BoxStoreBuilder.usePreviousCommit works internally?

Tags: android, objectbox

i converted my android app from mapdb to objectbox, i've seen on github a few people reporting database corruption with objectbox and the solution has always been to call usePreviousCommit in case of problems.

since the objectbox core is close source I wanted to know what usePreviousCommit does internally

- are there 2 physical copies of the database? and calling usePreviousCommit reverts to the previous copy?
- or does it work in a more complex way? (if yes i wanted to know how)

i opened this question because i want more information from objectbox before i continue to use it in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key word is [multiversion-concurrency](https://docs.objectbox.io/transactions#multiversion-concurrency). Think of a B+ tree with copy-on-write. The previous root tree (aka the previous commit) is preserved, so you can use when opening.